# FreeHand drawing Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener

I'm trying to create a program that I could draw a freehand drawing.
I created an array of points, and it saves the current point of the mouse.
The problem is when I release the mouse and then I  press it again in another location it draws line between the release point to the pressed point.
What should I add or change?

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mouse extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    private int index = 0;
    private Point[] arr = new Point[100000];

    public Mouse(String name) {
        super();
        index = 0;
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        JFrame fr = new JFrame(name);
        fr.add(this);
        fr.setSize(500, 500);
        setBackground(Color.green);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setVisible(true);

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
            g.drawLine(arr[i].x, arr[i].y, arr[i + 1].x, arr[i + 1].y);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        arr[index] = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
        index++;
        System.out.println(index);
        repaint();
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        arr[index] = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
        index++;
        System.out.println(index);
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mouse mouse = new Mouse("Mouse");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a pen up function?

Answer (score 2):

implement the mouseReleased method like this:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    arr = new Point[100000];
    index = 0;
}
```

this will cause it to work as you expect it.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
It is so simple, how I didn't figured it out by my self..
Anyway thankssssss

Comment: No problem, subash's code is a much better way to do it, however i wanted to modify your code as little as possible so i stuck with your original design.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
public class Mouse extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    private int x1 ;
    private int y1 ;
    private int cx,cy;
    public Mouse(String name) {
        super();
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        JFrame fr = new JFrame(name);
        fr.add(this);
        fr.setSize(500, 500);
        setBackground(Color.green);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawLine(cx, cy, x1, y1);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        x1 = e.getX();
        y1 = e.getY();
        cx = x1;
        cy = y1;
        repaint();
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        cx = e.getX();
        cy = e.getY();
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        cx = e.getX();
        cy = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mouse mouse = new Mouse("Mouse");

    }
}
```